# How to change ok button action in JOptionPane.showInputDialog

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have made a JOptionPane.showInputDialog in order to have 5 predefined queries in my implementation.
But when the user chooses an option and click on "ok" button the panel closes.
I want when the user click on "ok" button, the panel doesn't close but remains open so as the user could choose another query if he wants.
How i can change the "ok" button action? Is there a solution?
My code is as below:

```
...
String sparqlQueryString = new String();
String[] queryOptions = { "1. ...",
"2. ....",
"3. ...",
"4. ...",
5. ..."};

JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();        

String sparqlQueries = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, myPanel, "Predefined SparQL Queries", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, queryOptions, queryOptions[0]);
switch(sparqlQueries){
        case "1. ...":
        sparqlQueryString = ...
        myCode
        break;
        case "2. ...":
        sparqlQueryString = ...
        myCode
        break;
        case "3. ...":
        sparqlQueryString = ...
        myCode
        break;
        case "4. ...":
        sparqlQueryString = ...
        myCode
        break;
        case "5. ...":
        sparqlQueryString = ...
        myCode
        break;

if(!sparqlQueryString.isEmpty()) {
        File finalResults = new File(args[1]);
            try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(finalResults)) {
                StringBuilder results = new StringBuilder();

                Query query = QueryFactory.create(sparqlQueryString);
                QueryExecution qexec =     QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://localhost:8890/sparql", query, new PreemptiveBasicAuthenticator(new SimpleAuthenticator(virtuosoUserName, virtuosoPassword.toCharArray()), true));

                ResultSet resultSet = qexec.execSelect();
                List<String> columnNames = resultSet.getResultVars();
                while ( resultSet.hasNext() ) {
                    QuerySolution freqresult = resultSet.next();
                    int i = 0;
                    for(String var : columnNames)
                    {
                        i=i+1;
                        results.append(var).append(":");

                        if (freqresult.get(var) == null)
                            results.append("{null}");
                        else if (freqresult.get(var).isLiteral()) {
                             results.append(freqresult.getLiteral(var).toString().substring(freqresult.getLiteral(var).toString().lastIndexOf("#")+1)); 
                        }
                        else {
                            results.append(freqresult.getResource(var).toString().substring(freqresult.getResource(var).toString().lastIndexOf("#")+1));
                            //results.append(" ");
                        }
                        if(i!=columnNames.size()){
                            results.append(';');
                        }
                    }
                    results.append("\n");
                }
                int last = results.lastIndexOf("\n");
                if (last >= 0) { results.delete(last, results.length()); }
                //qexec.close();

                fileWriter.write(results.toString());
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a JOptionPane for this but rather use a non-modal JDialog ([JDialog API link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html)), one that stays open, since as a JDialog, you are in full control over when or whether it closes. These are easy to create, similar to JFrames except that in the constructor, you pass in the parent Window, often a JFrame, the title and the ModalityType, here ModalityType.MODELESS.

Comment: I want to have a drop down selection list so a user can select a query from that list. For this reason i used JOptionPane.showInputDialog. I didn't find how to make it with JDialog. Is there any solution?

Comment: @joan: Re `"I didn't find how..."` -- you're searching much too specifically, and you're never going to find an exact solution to your problem, but fortunately you can find solutions on how to solve each individual part of your problem, and then use your powerful brain to combine these small solutions into your own grand solution. That's what programming is all about. You know how to make a drop down selection list -- use a JComboBox, you know how to make a JDialog -- look at its API, construct it, and put your combo box into it, and then keep going til you find a solution. I have faith in you